# PHP MySQL Query with NOT LIKE specific id

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables. The first one is `messages` and the second is `room`. `msg_id` from `messages` table is the same as `id` from `room` table. What I'm doing is selecting all `msg_id` and for each of them I wanna run a query that deletes all rooms that their ids dont match with msg_id:

My code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `msg_id` FROM `messages`");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    $me = $row[0]; //$me as a string
    $int = (int)$me;//transform $me's value to int

  $result2 = mysql_query("DELETE FROM `room` WHERE `id` NOT LIKE '%" . $int . "%'");}
```

The `$result2` query will delete all entries from room table, no matter the value of `$int` variable. That means that the check is not working. If I change the `$result2` to this i.e.:

```
$result2 = mysql_query("DELETE FROM `room` WHERE `id` NOT LIKE '%86%'");
```

all entries will be Deleted except the room entry with `id = 86` (it works fine)

The basic plan is that I must keep all `room` entries that match their `id` with `msg_id` .

Comment: You are right it doesnt work fine for rooms 861 or 786, but my statement is that it works when using an int but not when using a php variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM `room` WHERE `id` NOT IN (SELECT `msg_id` FROM `messages`)
```

if you can't use subquery you can try:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `msg_id` FROM `messages`");
$ids = [];
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $ids[] = (int) $row[0];
}
$result2 = mysql_query("DELETE FROM `room` WHERE `id` NOT IN (" . implode(',', $ids) . "));
```

**and PLS don't USE mysql_query it is DEPRECATED**

Comment: I'm working on a non-updatable machine with PHP 5.1 and all running queries use mysql_query, so I'm running a cron job based on this, otherwise I wouldnt.

Comment: Well the subquery is not working so the ids array solution fixed it. Thank you @kallosz

Answer (score 0):

Could you use a subquery?

`DELETE FROM ROOM WHERE id not in(SELECT msg_id FROM messages);`

Answer (score -1):

Try this query,

```
delete from 'room' where 'id' not in(select 'msg_id' from 'messages');
```

if it don't work for you, you can try `NOT EQUAL TO` query

```
delete from 'room' where 'id' <>(select 'msg_id' from 'messages');
```